# How to get the current page URL using GWT in a Chrome extension?

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt

I'm developing a Chrome extension using GWT. I have to get the URL of the page when I open the extension. I have to do this because I need to read the page's contents to take some data.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with  [GWT.getModuleBaseURL()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getModuleBaseURL%28%29) and [GWT.getModuleName()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getModuleName%28%29) and [GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getHostPageBaseURL%28%29).

Look at other methods available in [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html) class for this purpose.

---

Output in DEV mode:

```
GWT.getModuleBaseURL(); 
GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();
GWT.getModuleName();
```

output:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8899/gwtproject/
http://127.0.0.1:8899/
gwtproject
```

Comment: Thanks but it not work.
It return 
chrome-extension://fllkecojollgpdflndacmfcl....
And i need that it return the url of the web page where i open the extension.

Comment: I have no idea about Chrome extension. I know how to get it in GWT only.